# Blazor PageTitle tag not working after migrating to .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, head

I tried to configure the page title in my Blazor Server application but, unfortunatelly, the tag `<PageTitle>` not working. This project was started before Microsoft release .NET Core 6 and, after that, I migrated my application to this version.

There aren't errors in compiling or running.

**Example page:**

```
@page "/page"

<PageTitle>My page title</PageTitle>

...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For using the `<PageTitle>` tag with the new version of .NET Core, server-side and not webAssembly, you need replace your `<title>` tag with a new component and add this library into the file `Pages/_Host.cshtml`.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

<head>
  <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
```

Project scaffolding created from .NET Core 6 adds these parts automatically in `Pages/_Layout.cshtml`

Theoretically, users with migrating WebAssembly projects need add too the code on below in `Program.cs`

```
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```