# How can I set the page title (the browser tab text) in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863542/how-to-set-page-title-in-blazor), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944916/pagetitle-template-component-method), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855310/blazor-pagetitle-tag-not-working-after-migrating-to-net-core-6). But they all strike me as a hack for something that should be straightforward. So I figure before implementing one of these approaches, I should ask if there's a clean straightforward way to do this.

Is there? Preferably one where I can set it in MainLayout and then optionally override that in other pages.

Comment: But you could use `<PageTitle>` in mainlayout and every pages to override.

Comment: As @QiangFu suggests, set `<PageTitle>Default Title</PageTitle>` in your layout./layouts  Then only add `<PageTitle>Page Title</PageTitle>` in pages where you want to override it.  I haven't added this as an answer as I'm only repeating the comment above.

Comment: @QiangFu Please write that as an answer and I will select it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<PageTitle></PageTitle>` in MainLayout to set title for all pages. And it can also be used in other pages to be override.